# Download XML file with JavaScript and C#/Rest

Tags: javascript, c#, xml, rest, wcf

I have an xml document that I generated in C#, I would like to return the string/document via WCF/REST so it will be downloaded by the browser. What is the operationcontract/return type that I should use? And how can I get it to be prompted to save by javascript and the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your operation contract should not be one way and you should return `Stream`

```
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetXml/{xmlFileName}")]
    Stream GetXml(string xmlFileName);

     public Stream GetXml(string xmlFileName)
    {
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

    string xmlLocation=GetXmlLocation(xmlFileName);

    try
    {
      return File.OpenRead(xmlLocation);
    }
    catch
    {
       // File Not Found

       return null;
    }



    }
```

Comment: This worked great. I converted the File.OpenRead to a MemoryStream so I didn't have to have a physical file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue with NodeJS backend.

I returned XML as a string and then on front-end I used next code:

```
 <a href="data:text/xml,HERE WILL BE YOUR XML" download="filename.xml">Download</a>
```